# I've two column HTML design. How do I make `#left` div consume as much space as possible (and be resizable), while `#right` stays constant size?

Tags: html, css

Here's HTML to illustrate the problem:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="left" style="float: left">
    left content
  </div>
  <div id="right" style="float: left; width: 250px">
    right content
  </div>
 </div>
```

How do I make `#left` take all the space in the container on the left and still make `#right` fit in there (taking 250px on the right)?

When resizing, I'd like `#left` to resize, but `#right` still be on the right size.

Any ideas how to do that?

I've tried the following but none of it works:

**1. add width 100% to #left**

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="left" style="float: left; width: 100%">
    left content
  </div>
  <div id="right" style="float: left; width: 250px">
    right content
  </div>
 </div>
```

This doesn't work - now `#left` takes 100% of content, and `#right` has been line-broken and pushed below it.

**2. add width 70% to #left**

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="left" style="float: left; width: 70%">
    left content
  </div>
  <div id="right" style="float: left; width: 250px">
    right content
  </div>
 </div>
```

This doesn't work because there is now a gap on the right. `#left` takes 70% of the space, but maybe there is 72% available.

Also this doesn't work because as I resize content to smaller than 70% + 250px, the `#right` column immediately line breaks and jumps below `#left`.

**3. add min-width: 100% to #left**

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="left" style="float: left; min-width: 100%">
    left content
  </div>
  <div id="right" style="float: left; width: 250px">
    right content
  </div>
 </div>
```

This doesn't work - `#left` now takes 100% again.

**4. add max-width: 100% to #left**

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="left" style="float: left; max-width: 100%">
    left content
  </div>
  <div id="right" style="float: left; width: 250px">
    right content
  </div>
 </div>
```

This doesn't work also - `#left` now takes 100% again.

**5. float `#right` to right**

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="left" style="float: left;">
    left content
  </div>
  <div id="right" style="float: right; width: 250px">
    right content
  </div>
 </div>
```

Doesn't really help. `#left` still takes a little space as possible.

**6. use `display: inline-block`**

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="left" style="display: inline-block">
    left content
  </div>
  <div id="right" style="display: inline-block; width: 250px">
    right content
  </div>
 </div>
```

Same thing as in original question. `#left` now takes as little space as there is in `left content`.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f0xed7a2/ This? If i understand correctly....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="left" >
    left content
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    right content
  </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#left {
    display:table-cell;
    background-color:red;
}
#right {
   display:table-cell;
    background-color:blue;
    width:250px;

}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f0xed7a2/

Based on your description, this should do the trick, good old tables...on CSS way.

Comment: Np, give me few minutes, basically same, just set new desired width for right content..

Comment: Thanks man! Waiting on the update. :) Cant believe it's the same ... I'd imagine I've to remove display: table-cell from left and right and have them wrap in natural div order. :) But you're the man so I'll follow what you say. :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f0xed7a2/1/ Here it is - just set desired width... all the rest - same. I love tables, too. :)

Comment: Yo that's almost it! Except I'd like #right to jump below #left in case content is 300px or less, and then both #right and #left take 100% of content (since they are below each other, i can display both 100%)

Comment: Ahh crap - another thing - I now see that #left's `margin-left` is no longer respected because it's table cells. Any way to add a small gap between #left and #right? Should I just use another table cell with width=10px? or something?

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track: http://jsfiddle.net/f0xed7a2/3/ So, basically, that should be it...

Comment: Yes, but, just in case... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout In this case - you needed fixed/fluid solution...

Comment: Hi nevermind again - I've run in an issue with `#left`'s width of 100%. In my app it somehow squeezes everything on the right, including spacer cell (which becomes 0px). Any ideas what could be happening?

Comment: No, to be honest. If you talk about smaller screen sizes (under 300px - btw are there such devices?:)) i set #margin to display:none, you can change ALL its properties inside media queries.... P.S. Width of #left shouldn't be 100% in any case (except on small screen size), it should be auto-calculated, use exact code from answer/fiddle, remove inline css, etc, etc...

Comment: Thanks I'm figuring this out. I've full screen browser (1100x1900). hmm.

Comment: I figured it out - it works now! Problem was that I applied widht:100% to #left, that caused everything to get squeezed. I'll accept your answer shortly. TY!

Comment: Hi again! Another follow up question - Can I apply a Media Query on `#left`? When left gets less than 300px (rather than the entire screen!). Thanks. :)

Comment: Np, thanks! As i assumed, inline styles made problems... Media queries can't be applied to elements, if you need further tweaking of elements behavior on different sizes - you will definitelly need javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have a two-column layout. You want the left column to occupy all available space and be re-sizable. You want the right column to remain a fixed width (250px).

This problem can be handled by [**CSS Flexbox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes).

HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="left">left content</div>
    <div id="right">right content</div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
#content { display: flex; }
#left { flex-grow: 1; }
#right { flex: 0 0 250px; }
@media (max-width: 300px) { #content { flex-direction: column; } }
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/jn7kqv8g/

***Here's what's happening...***

1. The `display: flex` declaration makes `div#content` a flexbox. The children of the flexbox (known technically as "flex items") are aligned in a row by default (`flex-direction: row`). Hence, both `div#left` and `div#right` are now in one row.
2. The `flex-grow: 1` declaration in `div#left` gives this box all available width.
3. The `flex: 0 0 250px` declaration is shorthand for three properties:

   - `flex-grow: 0` (box should not grow)
   - `flex-shrink: 0` (box should not shrink)
   - `flex-basis: 250px` (initial size is 250px)

   Altogether, this results in a box that remains fixed at 250px width.
4. Lastly, the media query switches the flexbox alignment from row to column when the screen size is less than 300px (per your requirement in comments).

In case you're interested, here's a good reference guide to flex properties:
 [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Cool this also works! Any ideas about browser compatibility? I still support IE9...

Comment: Michael - thanks but IE9 not supported :( Any other alternatives you can think of? Please leave your answer though - it's very valuable for anyone IE10+!